# 301 redirects for urls ending in numbers and contain folder name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to place 301 redirects from old urls which look something like
`http://www.domain.com/news/blocked-drainage/drain-cleaning-companies-help-in-restoring-your-clogged-drains/408`

To

`http://www.domain.com/blocked-drainage/drain-cleaning-companies-help-in-restoring-your-clogged-drains/`

so two changes, firstly now `news` folder in new urls and secondly no numbers at the end of the urls.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^news\/(.+)\/([0-9]+)$ /blocked-drainage/$1/ [R=301]
```

(Novocaine88’s answer won’t work, because RewriteRule only tries to match against the *path* component of the URL.)

Comment: Simplify it: `RewriteRule ^news/(.+?)/([0-9]+)/?$ /blocked-drainage/$1/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: @anubhava I once saw `/` escaped in the replacement text as well. :)

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: Agree, I have also seen that and it doesn't harm but not needed.

Comment: @CBroe +1 this should work but don't capture numbers `()` and add an optional slash `/[0-9]+/?$`

Comment: @anubhava: Yeah, people love Windows :)

Comment: thank you all. Now if I want to replace news in all url with latest-news? e.g 

http://www.domain.com/news/blocked-drainage/drain-cleaning-companies-help-in-restoring-your-clogged-drains/408

To

http://www.domain.com/latest-news/blocked-drainage/drain-cleaning-companies-help-in-restoring-your-clogged-drains/408

Comment: We showed you how to rewrite from `/news/…` to `/blocked-drainage/…` – and now to add `/latest-news` before that you seriously have to ask again …? C’mon, please show that you’re not only waiting for copy&paste-ready answers, but that you think a little bit for yourself as well. Give it a try, and if you encounter problems with it, then we can discuss them again – but a little bit of an own effort first please!